# Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are integrable on $[a,b]$, then so are $\max{(f,g)}$ and $\min{(f,g)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are integrable on $[a,b]$, then so are $\max{(f,g)}$ and $\min{(f,g)}$.

Since $f$ and $g$ are integrable, we know that $U(f,\mathcal{P})-L(f,\mathcal{P}) < \epsilon$ over each interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ as we refine $\mathcal{P}$. Similarly $U(g,\mathcal{P}) - L(g,\mathcal{P}) < \epsilon$. Therefore we know that $$\sum_{i=1}^n M_i(x_i-x_{i-1})-\sum_{i=1}^n m_i(x_i-x_{i-1})<\epsilon$$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^n M_i'(x_i-x_{i-1})-\sum_{i=1}^n m_i'(x_i-x_{i-1})<\epsilon.$$ How do I continue from here?

Comment: " Since f and g are integrable..." That sentence needs work. What we know is there is a partition P such that U(f,P) - L(f,P) < epsilon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Here is a different approach. Writing $\varphi(x) = \max \{f(x), g(x)\}$ and $\psi(x) = \{f(x), g(x)\}$ then since $f$ and $g$ are integrable you can use

$$\varphi = \frac{1}{2}[f+g + |f - g|]\,\,\, \text{and} \,\,\,\, \psi = \frac{1}{2} [f + g - |f - g|]$$

and that the sum of integrable functions is integrable.

Comment: For what it's worth, to see why the absolute value of an integrable function is still integrable, an appeal to the triangle inequality yields that $$U(|f|,P)-L(|f|,P)\le U(f,P)-L(f,P).$$